# Terraform rename a resource without deleting

Tags: terraform

I created AzDo repositories using the Terraform. **But what is the best way to rename the repository without deleting it.** I found a command "terraform state mv" for the purpose. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Currently when I use the Terraform state mv command I'm getting below error

```
 terraform state mv "module.azdo-module.azuredevops_git_repository[\"repo1\"]" "module.azdo-module.azuredevops_project.azuredevops_git_repository[\"repo2\"]"
```

Getting below error

```
  Error: Invalid address
 │ 
 │   on  line 1:
 │   (source code not available)
 │ 
 │ A resource name is required.
```

Comment: That namespace in the command is invalid, which is why that error message is thrown. Please update with a snippet of the resource config for which you are renaming the state.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Could you be more specific to the solution. What namespace you are referring to?. it will be so great if you provide me a reference URL or how to use the correct command

Answer (score 40):

Terraform has introduced a new declarative way to refactor resources with the move block syntax in 1.1 version.

Steps:

1. Rename the resource to the new name
2. Add

   ```
   moved {
     from = module.azdo-module.azuredevops_git_repository.repo1
     to   = module.azdo-module.azuredevops_project.azuredevops_git_repository.repo2
   }
   ```

   (The original names can be listed by `terraform state list`)
3. Update references to a new resource name
4. `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`
5. Remove the moved block (given no one else is using your modules)

More info:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax

Comment: The better solution is described below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70427177/4632019

Answer (score 24):

maybe

`terraform state mv "module.azdo-module.azuredevops_git_repository.repo1" "module.azdo-module.azuredevops_project.azuredevops_git_repository.repo2"`

list resources to check the name

`terraform state list`

Comment: Wow
The "terraform state list" helped me to find out the correct syntax. 
Once we changed the state what should be done to reflect the change in the target

Comment: But this will remove the resource and recreate it. tried the same for aws secrets manager resource creation. It did create new secrets with did resource ARN @david

Comment: Since terraform v1.1+ it is now much better to use the `moved { from... to ... }` block per the other answer.

Comment: It is more safer to use `terraform state mv` instead of `terraform plan/apply`. By applying you can occasionally apply different changes. Not only those resources which were renamed.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to use double quotes in the command else it errors saying no resource found
terraform stat mv "old" "new"